# allow user to edit student info from a binary file in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, binaryfiles

I am working on a school project. It basically allows the user to create a Student using scanner, assigns and id to the student and then writes the data into a binary file called studentsinfo.dat. Once the student has been created the user can either display the info from the binary file or edit student. I got the displaying part working. However, I am having trouble to allow them to edit, the program asks the user to enter the student id to edit, the program should check if the user input exists in the file but I am having problem been able to move the file pointer so it looks for the id and compare it with the user input, I have tried some stuff but not working. Any ideas would be appreciated, here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.io.*;
public class MidTermProject {
    
    static AtomicInteger idGenerator = new AtomicInteger(0001);
    static int id;
    
    public static int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ///Create Student method
    public static void CreateStudent() throws IOException {
        String FullName;
        String address;
        String city;
        String state;
        String newStudentID;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        FileOutputStream fstream =
                new FileOutputStream("StudentInfo.dat", true);
        DataOutputStream outputFile =
                new DataOutputStream(fstream);
        
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your information bellow.\n" + "\nFull Name: ");
        FullName = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(FullName);
        
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        address = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(address);
        
        System.out.print("City: ");
        city = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(city);
        
        System.out.print("State: ");
        state = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(state);
        
        id = idGenerator.getAndIncrement();
        String student = Integer.toString(getId());
        outputFile.writeUTF(student);
    
        outputFile.close();
        
        System.out.print("\nDone\n");
        
    }
    ///Edit Student method
    public static void EditStudent() throws IOException {
        String editName;
        String editaddress;
        String editCity;
        String editState;
        int editID;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the ID of the student you would like to edit: ");
        editID = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        RandomAccessFile file = 
            new RandomAccessFile("StudentInfo.dat", "rw");
        file.seek(10);
            
        char ch = file.readChar();
            
        if(editID == ch) {
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter NEW information bellow.\n" + "\nFull Name: ");
            editName = keyboard.nextLine();
            file.writeUTF(editName);
                
            System.out.print("Address: ");
            editaddress = keyboard.nextLine();
            file.writeUTF(editaddress);
                
            System.out.print("City: ");
            editCity = keyboard.nextLine();
            file.writeUTF(editCity);
                
            System.out.print("State: ");
            editState = keyboard.nextLine();
            file.writeUTF(editState);
                
            file.close();
                
            System.out.print("Successfully Edited");
        } else {
            System.out.print("error");
        }
    }
    ///Display Student method
    public static void DisplayStudent() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("StudentInfo.dat");
        DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        
        String student;
        boolean endOfFile = false;
        
        while(!endOfFile)
        {
            try
            {
                student = inputFile.readUTF();
                System.out.print(student + "\n");
            }
            catch (EOFException e)
            {
                endOfFile = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nDone");
        
        inputFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to edit the file in-place instead of reading the data into memory, editing in memory, then serializing the data back into a file? The end result is the same, and both would count as editing the student records.

Comment: @thatotherguy you are correct. We are learning from the book starting out with java and part of that chapter is serialized objects, I didn't really know how to explain it. Trying to figure that out

Comment: I meant "serialize" in the general sense of writing them sequentially to file and not Java Serialization but sure

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are trying to enter the students' records line by line, so when you edit you will seek for that line and edit it there, is that right? If so you would at least need to separate the records when you are storing them e.g. by adding a \n at the end of the line to then write the next record on a new line and then you should be able to update the records on a certain line based on the id. You could implement the toString() method of Student class and just write once to the file - student1.toString() which on the inside will combine all the data into one string.

Additionally, you are writing the student data strings on top of each other so as a result, you will get JohnDoeAddressCity which will be then hard to parse back to a Student instance. Consider dividing the value e.g. with a comma - "Name Surname, Address, City".